# Connecting two computers residing on different networks using python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am developing a voice + audio chat app. I have successfully created the web app which runs on the computers residing on the same network. Now I want to make upgradation in my project and want to connect the computers of different networks. I ave developed the web app in python. Please tell me how to connect the two computers over the different network using python only?

Comment: This requires tinkering with the routers. Look into port forwarding.

Comment: Any link to the blog, tutorial

Comment: What you mean by different networks ? are this networks part of a business? you want to connect users from different ISP's ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058588/how-send-data-between-two-devices-using-sockets-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

[Port forwarding](https://portforward.com/) - this one explains how to port forward on specific routers. Basically what you want to do is port forward any ports used by the server of your web app (this is usually only the port 80 for web apps) on your local router. Then find out your global IP somewhere like [What is my ip?](https://www.whatsmyip.org/). After that you can connect to the server from anywhere outside your local network using your global IP.

Comment: Okay I'll see to it. The only thing I have to ensure is the IP of the PCs and the fetching process should be smooth. Rest it will work by using the socket library.